# Result of map and mapAsync(1) in Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

My code which uses `mapAync(1)` doesn't work what I want it to do. But when I changed the  `mapAsync(1)` to `map` by using `Await.result`, it works. So I have a question. 
**Does the following `(A) Use map` and `(B) use mapAsync(1)` yield the same result at anytime?**

```
// (A) Use map
someSource
 .map{r => 
   val future = makeFuture(r) // returns the same future if r is the same
   Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
 }

// (B) Use mapAsync(1)
someSource
 .mapAsync(1){r =>
   val future = makeFuture(r) // returns the same future if r is the same
   future
}
```

Actually, I want to paste my real code, but it is too long to paste and has some dependencies of my original stages.

Comment: `mapAsync` itself returns a `Future[T]`, I don't think there's actually a need to wrap that with another future made by `makeFuture`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Sorry, but I couldn't  understand what you said. I think `Source[O, Mat]#mapAsync[T](par: Int)(f: O => Future[T])` returns  `Source[T, Mat]`, not `Future[T]`.

Comment: What does the code for `makeFuture` look like and what is the type of `r`?

Comment: Sorry for my kindless code. In my real code, the type of `r` is `akka.util.ByteString`, but I think the type can be anything.

Comment: Thanks to you and other answerers, my code did work what I wanted it do. In the process of making reproduction code, I collected my mistakes. The mistakes was in my original GraphStage. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

While semantically the type of both streams ends up being the same (`Source[Int, NotUsed]`), the style displayed in example `(A)` is very very bad – please don't block (`Await`) inside streams.

Such cases are exactly the use case for `mapAsync`. Your operation returns a `Future[T]`, and you want to push that value downwards through the stream once the future completes. Please note that there is *no blocking* in mapAsync, it schedules a callback to push the value of the future internally and does so once it completes.

To answer your question about "do they do the same thing?", technically yes but the first one will cause performance issues in the threadpool you're running on, avoid map+blocking when mapAsync can do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I want to use `mapAsync`, but in my particular code `mapAsync` doesn't work. So, I replaced `mapAsync` with `map` and `Await` by the way of `(A)`. Then my code works. But I don't understand why the replacement affects the result. To know the reason, I asked. I want to paste the code, but it is too long. So I'll try to make the phenomenon in short code.

Comment: I think there must be something else going on in your code, the mapAsync likely is not at fault here. Please try to find a reproducer

Comment: Yes, you are right! `mapAsync` wasn't  at fault. Thanks to you and other answerers, my code did work what I wanted it do. In the process of making reproduction code, I collected my mistakes. The mistakes was in my original GraphStage. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

These calls are semantically very similar, although blocking by using `Await` is probably not a good idea. The type signature of both these calls is, of course, the same (`Source[Int, NotUsed]`), and in many cases these calls will produce the same results (blocking aside). The following, for example, which includes scheduled futures and a non-default supervision strategy for failures, gives the same results for both map with an Await inside and mapAsync:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream.ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy
import akka.stream.Supervision.resumingDecider
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import system.scheduler

    def makeFuture(r: Int) = {
      akka.pattern.after(2 seconds, scheduler) {
        if (r % 3 == 0)
          Future.failed(new Exception(s"Failure for input $r"))
        else
          Future(r + 100)
      }
    }

    val someSource = Source(1 to 20)

    val mapped = someSource
      .map { r =>
        val future = makeFuture(r)
        Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
      }.withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider))

    val mappedAsync = someSource
      .mapAsyncUnordered(1) { r =>
        val future = makeFuture(r)
        future
      }.withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider))

    mapped runForeach println
    mappedAsync runForeach println

  }

}
```

It is possible that your upstream code is relying on the blocking behaviour in your map call in some way. Can you produce a concise reproduction of the issue that you are seeing?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
> Can you produce a concise reproduction of the issue that you are seeing?
Actually, before asking, I tried to make a simple reproduction of the issue code, but I couldn't . But I'll retry to make one.

Comment: Thanks to you and other answerers, my code did work what I wanted it do. In the process of making reproduction code, I collected my mistakes. The mistakes was in my original `GraphStage`. Thank you very much!